# Conemu: How can I cycle through SplitScreen windows?

Tags: conemu

How can I cycle through SplitScreen windows?

I can only find a NextConsole shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, "cycle" exactly? There is no special shotcut for this action. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> use common (and intuitive) combo for switching between tabs. But I can't remember any "well known" combo for splits.

BTW, when you start switching tabs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> you may press <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> to goto left or right tab.

**Update**

[Build 121119](https://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/) or higher allows switching between visible panes with <kbd>Apps</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Apps</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

And it is possible now to close visible panes (active group) from tab menu, system menu or keyboard shortcut (unassigned by default).

Comment: In tmux in linux it's called next-pane. Sometimes it's nice to have a command line and a text editor in two panes; then toggle back and forth. If I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> and I have other tabs open I often end up in the next window.

Comment: And what hotkey provides tmux?

Comment: Tmux uses a prefix scheme, like emacs. The hotkey is <kbd>o</kbd>, but you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> first.

Comment: Prefix schemes are not supported by conemu, may be in future... Thought, Apps+Tab may be used for requested action.

Comment: What is Apps? Is it a media key?

Comment: It is a key near to right Win

Comment: Update to build 121119 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

AutoHotKey script that will toggle between two panes.

```
Toggle_Pane() {
    global pane_toggle
    pane_toggle := !pane_toggle
    if pane_toggle
        ControlClick, VirtualConsoleClass1
    else
        ControlClick, VirtualConsoleClass2
    return
}

SC056 & o::Toggle_Pane()
```